# capture image from web camera

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to learn ocaml and I want get image from web camera. I'm reading [Unix system programming in OCaml](http://ocamlunix.forge.ocamlcore.org/ocamlunix.html)

How can I get picture from my web camera on linux operating system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On linux you can use [V4L2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux) - a video capture application programming interface for Linux. Many USB webcams, TV tuners, and other devices are supported. Video4Linux is closely integrated with the Linux kernel.

Look at simple examples (in C programming language):

- [one](http://web.archive.org/web/20110707012738/http://alumnos.elo.utfsm.cl/~yanez/video-for-linux-2-sample-programs/)
- [two](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/capture-example.html)

You can use `ioctl` linux system call in your OCaml program. Look at this modules:

1. libextunix-ocaml-dev
2. [pleac-ocaml](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ocaml/index.html)